# SQL Server - round to one decimal - values like 0.84

Tags: sql, sql-server, rounding

How to round up decimal value to 1 when this is decimal like 0.5 or 0.84?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ceiling-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 ?

Comment: Have you tried... `ROUND`..?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [CEILING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ceiling-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) , but a better approach if you have numbers like `367.375000` is to combine `CEILING` with `ROUND` like:

```
select ceiling(round(your_column, 0)) as rounded_nr  ;
```

Result:

```
rounded_nr
     367
```

While

```
select ceiling(367.375000)  as rounded_nr ;
```

will return:

```
rounded_nr
  368
```

and

```
select round(367.375000, 0) as rounded_nr ;
```

will return

```
rounded_nr
 367.000000
```

Check the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b73c4de286438d46c515df3c214eda46)

Answer (score -2):

Just try round(value, decimals)